# Leaflet plugins

Tags: angular, leaflet

I'm using leaflet in an Angular project and I need to integrate plugin for leaflet, but they are all pure js . The problem is I don't get to make them work.
I've tryed :

```js
import * as L from "leaflet";
import 'leaflet.measurecontrol';

declare module 'leaflet' {
 export namespace Control {
    export let measureControl: any;
  }
}

onMapReady(map: L.Map) {
    this.map = map;
    L.Control.measureControl().addTo(map);
}
```

I there a specific way to integrate plugins ?

Comment: did you include the plugin into angular.json under the scripts array?

Comment: Yes, still doesn't recognize in app , and doesn't work. :( . I tried adding to scripts , i tried adding in HTML under <link> tag , i tried creating types.d.ts file , nothing works.

Comment: try this tsconfig option https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs

Comment: I tried now , nothings changed... . But the problem is that leaflet dosn't recognize the plugin , i mean after i import everything from 'leaflet' in alias L . the classes from plugins doesn't appear under L .

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: In a sort of way , i solved it , i cut off the import thing , but installed npm package and got recognized. Thanks